# Unable to remove Kwikset Deadbolt

Tags: deadbolt

I'm 99% sure this is a Kwikset 660 Smartkey deadbolt (has the rekey tool hole on the front).
I moved into an apartment complex and wanted to install an August lock (property management was ok with this after talking to them).
I've installed this lock before on a previous home, and I don't remember there be anything tricky about installing/uninstalling this lock.

I taped the outside lock so it wouldn't fall off.
Inside, I turned the lock to the unlocked position to expose the screws.
I removed both screws.
But when I pulled on the deadbolt, it didn't come off.  Still felt securely fastened in place.
I looked for a hex key hole in case there was some kind of set screw holding it in place.
On neither the deadbolt side or the outside lock side did I see anything like this.
I tried squirting some WD-40 in case it was stuck/wedged, but no luck.

I'm starting to suspect the deadbolt has been "glued" onto the "D" torque blade, but that just seems insane.

Before running off to maintenance, is there anything non-destructive I could try to get this removed?

I would supply images but there's not much I can get a picture of internally.

Comment: You pulled on the deadbolt and it came off. So what is the problem?

Comment: Unhappy renters or punks glue locks at rentals all the time, I used to help a “slum lord” friend of mine and glued locks is not unusual. I used a battery drill and although it destroys the lock with a good cobalt drill it is usually done in a minute.

Comment: @SolarMike That was supposed to be "didn't come off".  I updated the question.